# "an object reference is required to access non-static field"

Tags: c#, sql, linq, wcf

I have this code in my WCF service implementation, and I get this error
:

```
 'an object reference is required to access non-static field, method or property    
   System.Data.Linq.DataContext.User.get
```

How can I update the user's location properly? Here is the code:

```
public  void UpdateLocation(string usrName, double usrLong, double usrLat)
        {

            var result = (from usr in DataClasses1DataContext.Users
                          where usr.usrName == usrName
                          select usr).Single();
            result.usrLong = usrLong;
            result.usrLat = usrLat;
            DataClasses1DataContext.SubmitChanges();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ian mentioned,

```
public  void UpdateLocation(string usrName, double usrLong, double usrLat)
{
    using(DataClasses1DataContext Usercontext = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var result = (from usr in Usercontext.Users where usr.usrName == usrName select usr).Single();

        result.usrLong = usrLong;
        result.usrLat = usrLat;

        Usercontext.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: People who downvote! even though Ian's answer was right, the OP has added a comment on his answer by creating a instance of user, to make him clear i added this answer!

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you all you need to know, the `Users` property is not static but you are calling it as thought it were. You need an instance of a `DataClasses1DataContext` to call the property from:

```
using(DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
   var result = (from usr in context.Users
                          where usr.usrName == usrName
                          select usr).Single();
}
```